# How to launch tmux –automatically– when konsole/yakuake start?

Tags: terminal, tmux, konsole, yakuake

I discovered `tmux` possibility recently and I'm using it inside `yakuake`/`konsole` (quake-like terminal). However, I have to launch `tmux` manually every time I start my laptop or restart `yakuake`.

How to **launch `tmux` –automatically– when `yakuake`/`konsole` start** ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the [Start tmux on every shell login](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Tmux#Start_tmux_on_every_shell_login) article from the Archlinux wiki, you can start `tmux` on your shell with the following code at the

### `Zsh` or `Bash`

Add in your `zsh` or `bash` configuration (usually `~/.zshrc` or `~/.bashrc`) the following code and restart your session:

```bash
function start_tmux() {
    if type tmux &> /dev/null; then
        #if not inside a tmux session, and if no session is started, start a new session
        if [[ $HOST == "laptop" && -z "$TMUX" && -z $TERMINAL_CONTEXT ]]; then
            (tmux -2 attach || tmux -2 new-session)
        fi
    fi
}
start_tmux
```

### `Fish`

Add in your `fish` configuration (usually `~/.config/fish/config.fish`) the following code and restart your session:

```
function start_tmux
    if type tmux > /dev/null
        #if not inside a tmux session, and if no session is started, start a new session
        if test -z "$TMUX" ; and test -z $TERMINAL_CONTEXT
            tmux -2 attach; or tmux -2 new-session
        end
    end
end

start_tmux
```

Comment: this is amazing, and works in both linux and mac, thanks so much!~

Answer (score 6):

A friend advice to use `<terminal_emulator> -e tmux`.

### Konsole

It works with `konsole`.

I modified the property in the menu to:

```
konsole -e tmux
```

### Yakuake

However it **doesn't work with `yakuake`**.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by creating a Konsole/Yakuake profile (they're one and the same) + made it the default, in which I set up the `Command` to:

```sh
/usr/bin/sh -ilc "tmux attach || tmux new"
```

Manage profiles + where the profile is located, in case Yakuake/Konsole doesn't start up anymore:
[image: How to manage Konsole/Yakuake profile and where the file is located]

Answer (score 1):

When yakuake is running:

```
qdbus org.kde.yakuake /yakuake/sessions runCommandInTerminal 0 "tmux"
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried with Yakuake but I have a one liner shell scripting approach to make it work with Konsole Terminal Emulator.

Konsole emulator set `KONSOLE_<something>` environment variable on start.

Knowing this fact, we can add this to `.zshrc` file

```sh
[ -z "$KONSOLE_VERSION" ] || tmux
```

And this will start all KONSOLE windows attached to active tmux session or create one if its the first window.